# Does Day of Judgment remove hexproof / shrouded creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Wrath of God really destroy creatures with shroud?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/does-wrath-of-god-really-destroy-creatures-with-shroud)

Does this:

[image: Day of Judgment]

or other similar cards remove any hexproof / shrouded creatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Since the creature is not targeted, but is being affected by a global property neither hexproof nor shroud offer any protection.

> 702.17a Shroud is a static ability. “Shroud” means “This permanent or player can’t be the target of spells or abilities.”
>
> 702.11b “Hexproof” on a permanent means “This permanent can’t be the target of spells or abilities your opponents control.”

In both cases "not being targeted" is the key.

Comment: If I think through this logically it seems that this spell targets ALL creatures. How can your spell destroy a creature if it does not target it?

Comment: From where did you copy that rule btw? I always see those cryptic paragraps (like 702.17a) but I don't know where do they came from.

Comment: @edem : You explicitly need the keyword "target" on the card. Day of Judgment does not destroy "target creatures" but "all creatures".

Comment: @edem See the [Magic Rules](http://wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/rules) page. Each line of the Comprehensive Rules is numbered.