# Ways to remove creatures with Shroud

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was playing Forge last night and the computer brought out [Wall of Denial](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wall%20of%20Denial).  What an annoying wall!  Is there any way to destroy it other than attacking with a big creature and having the wall block the creature.  It says it can't be the target of spells or abilities.  Any other ways to destroy it?

Comment: Literally any wrath ever.

Comment: So you're talking about Wrath of God or Kirtar's Wrath I'm guessing?  I was hoping to just destroy the wall, not all my creatures as well.

Comment: May wish to specify that in the question then.

Comment: I think this question can't be answered well unless colors, or even better a more specific deck is mentioned in the question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Wrath of God really destroy creatures with shroud?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/does-wrath-of-god-really-destroy-creatures-with-shroud) The answers to that question clarify that creatures with Shroud and other protective abilities can still be destroyed by sweeper spells and give examples of what cards are able to do that.

Comment: @Hackworth I don't think this is a duplicate of that. This question is asking for ways to kill a shroud creature; that one is asking whether a particular method actually kills shroud creatures.

Comment: Author, are you opposed to changing the title of your question to "Ways to remove creatures with Shroud"? I think being less specific here would improve the overall usefulness of the question.

Comment: @Rainbolt, that's a good idea; done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are. A creature with shroud can't be the target of spells or abilities, but it still can be effected by ones that don't target.

Some examples are ones that destroy all creatures like [Wrath of God](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wrath%20of%20God), deals enough damage to all creatures like [Blasphemous Act](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blasphemous%20Act), or gives all creatures -X/-X like [Black Sun's Zenith](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=389442).

Another common way of dealing with shrouded creatures is by forcing its controller to sacrifice it with something like [Diabolic Edict](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Diabolic%20Edict), though this require them to only have one creature, or want to keep their other creatures more than the wall.

You can also remove shroud from the wall either with [Arcane Lighthouse](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arcane%20Lighthouse) or cards that remove all abilities without targeting like [Polymorphist's Jest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383351).

You could also give smaller creatures that it blocks deathtouch with something like [Coat with Venom](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Coat%20with%20Venom).

Comment: Sudden Spoiling is another consideration to mention.

Comment: Diabolic Edict is a good one remove removing creatures with Shroud.

Comment: Sacrifice effects in general are a pretty common answer for shroud/hexproof. Beyond that, it's just one wall; if you can attack with multiple creatures it can't really save them.

Answer (score 5):

Just the usual answers to shroud/hexproof, including board wipes like [Supreme Verdict](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=253512) and spells that don't have the word *target* in them.

If you already have removal in your deck, you might want to sideboard in [Arcane Lighthouse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=389430), which is useful for being able to get rid of shroud/hexproof creatures.

Answer (score 4):

**Eliminate it Directly**

The obvious answer is to just get rid of it directly, with a non-targeting effect.  Here's two that I have found, I'd be very interested in others that people know of:  [Council Judgement](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Council%20Judgement), [Porphyry Nodes](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Porphyry%20Nodes) and [drop of honey](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=drop%20of%20honey).

That said, the possibilities here are truly almost endless.  So, let us walk through ways around this problem...

**WIPE the BOARD**

There's nothing quite like brute forcing your way through a problem.  In multi-player, don't be surprised if you get countered though....  [Wrath of God](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wrath%20of%20God) is the obvious example here, but there are almost [100 cards that give you a massive board wipe](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5B%22destroy%20all%20creatures%22%5D).

**Damage all Flying Creatures**

The above is a bit brutal, a "softer" way is to "just" damage the flying creatures.  There are about [10 spells](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5Bflying%5D%20%5BX%5D%20%5Bdamage%5D%20%5Bcreature%5D%20!%5Btarget%5D) that can do this.  [Windstorm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Windstorm) is a nice one.

**Damage it indirectly**

There are a number of cards that can do this, but some related to creature types are: [Coordinated Barrage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Coordinated%20Barrage), although [Engineered Plague](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Engineered%20Plague), [Outbreak](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Outbreak), [Roar of the Crowd](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Roar%20of%20the%20Crowd).  These can be considered variants of "Damage all flying creatures"

**Force your opponent to Sacrifice it**

- Cast a spell/use an effect that forces your opponent to sacrifice a creature.  There are roughly [50 cards](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5Bsacrifice%5D%20%5Bcreature%5D%7C%5B%22target%20player%22%5D%7C%5B%22opponent%22%5D) that can be used to do this.  [far](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=far) and [away](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=away) is an obvious example
- attack with any creature that has  [annihilator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5Bannihilator%5D)

**Force your opponent to block your deathtouch or massive creature**

- [Deadly Allure](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Deadly%20Allure) is the best card for this.  Although [Irresistable Prey](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Irresistable%20Prey) works nicely as well as a cantrip.  In all there are 10 cards that match the "[must block](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5Bmust%5D%20%5Bblock%5D)" description.
- There are roughly 100 cards that have, or can give [deathtouch](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5Bdeathtouch%5D).
- There are roughly 100 creatures that have [power 8 or greater](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&power=%20%3E=%5B8%5D), and I'm not counting cards that can pump a creature's power like [Giant Growth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Giant%20Growth) or [Titantic Growth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Titantic%20Growth).

**Force it to lose shroud**

I think this is clear enough.  How to do that is a bit tricky, as you can't target it.  But there are a variety of ways:

- [Arcane Lighthouse](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arcane%20Lighthouse).
- [Humility](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Humility)
- [Polymorphist Jest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Polymorphist%20Jest)
- [Sudden Spoiling](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sudden%20Spoiling)

**Force it to lose flying**

Not quite what you had in mind, but still helpful.  I can't find many cards to do this however:

- [Gravity Sphere](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gravity%20Sphere)
- [Invert the Skies](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Invert%20the%20Skies)
- [Archetype of Imagination](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Archetype%20of%20Imagination)
- [Mystic Decree](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mystic%20Decree)
- [Thundercloud Elemental](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thundercloud%20Elemental)
- [Whiteout](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Whiteout)

**Wear it Down**

Attack it with a creature that has [wither or infect](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%7C%5Bwither%5D%7C%5Binfect%5D), (over 100 options) i.e. does damage with -1/-1 counters.  Use a "force to block" effect described above to force the block.

**Take it out of Combat**

Force it to tap, before it can block and affect you.  I can't find a good search criteria for this.  Since it has shroud, you'll have to tap all their creatures, but hey, that's just gravy!  Some examples are:

- [Cryptic Command](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cryptic%20Command)
- [Angel's Trumpet](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Angel%27s%20Trumpet) is an interesting card.
- [Ensnare](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ensnare)
- [Turnabout](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Turnabout)
- [Sleep](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sleep) this is my kids' current favorite card lately.  They beat me all the time with this one.

**Avoid It**

These approaches may not apply to your case, you wanted to destroy it, but really, avoiding it is a perfectly legitimate strategy to deal with any threat.

- [Riders of Gavony](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Riders%20of%20Gavony) can avoid it nicely.
- Intimidate:  There are about 35 cards that have or give [intimidate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5Bintimidate%5D&color=%20!%5BB%5D%20!%5BU%5D).
- Fear:  There are roughly 70 cards that have or affect [fear](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5Bfear%5D).
- Shadow: There are roughly 60 cards that give or have [shadow](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5Bshadow%5D).
- [Plainswalk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5Bplainswalk%5D):
- [Mountainwalk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5Bmountainwalk%5D):
- [IslandWalk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5Bislandwalk%5D)
- [SwampWalk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5Bswampwalk%5D)
- [ForestWalk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5Bforestwalk%5D)

There are lots of other "can't be blocked" creatures, those are just some ideas to get you going.

**Overwhelm It**

Cast another great creature.  Or create a creature army....  The list here is too long to go into, but [Sacred Mesa](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sacred%20Mesa) & [Goblin Warrens](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Goblin%20Warrens) are personal favorites.

Comment: Your very first suggestion does work, but I think the "exile it" header is misleading. The reason it works is that Council's Judgment doesn't target, not that it exiles things. Good list, though!

Comment: Harsh Mercy won't work. Your opponent can just select Wall as the type they want to save.